# How can I make an Android app a system app so that I can use it to shutdown phone?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, root

I want to use the this Intent

`android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN`

to shutdown my android phone programmatically. However, based on my research, I've found that only system apps have the authority to do this. Now my question is, how do I make my app a system app? The app is written in Kotlin.

I tried a different approach - rooting the phone via Magisk and running a this subprocess-

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this did not work. I'm uncertain if the systemless rooting with Magisk is the cause for this.